# I want to target the body tag except one element

Tags: jquery, css

It is making everything blur even the `.not` or `:not` element

```
$("#team").mouseenter(function(){
    $('body').not('#team').css("-webkit-filter", "blur(2px)");
});

$("p").mouseleave(function(){
    $('body').not('#team').css("-webkit-filter", "blur(0px)");
});
```

Comment: You cannot do it. The `blur` filter will filter the element and all its contents. You cannot exclude a child element.

Comment: something like `$('body:not(#team)').css("-webkit-filter", "blur(0px)");` ?

Comment: Broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation of what is expected and a [mcve]

Comment: @demo still the same problem. I dont know how to exclude a child element here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('body').not('#team')
```

means any `<body>` element that does not have `id="team"`. It does not mean any element inside `$('body')` that does not have `id="team"`.

You'd need `$("body,body *").not('#team')` to select all items without `id="team"`. or
`$('*', $('body')).not('#team')` (this one doesn't include `<body>` - only contents).

However, I **strongly** recommend against such a selector, for two reasons:

1. It would be outrageously expensive
2. It wouldn't work for the CSS property you are trying to apply.

When you apply `-webkit-filter:blur(Npx)` on an element, you are blurring that element together with its contents. If any of the children also has `-webkit-filter(Npx)`, the filter gets applied twice, once for child and once for parent. And this goes for each subsequent child.

That's why I said it's *"outrageously"* expensive. You'll effectively kill (or at least stall a bit) machines without a powerful rendering engine, depending on the number of elements in your page and size in pixels of your page/viewport. It's possible some browsers implement a prevention mechanism against this type of abusive rendering processing requests from pages and they might skip applying the filter on children of parents that already have a similar filter (although, from where I see it, it would be wrong - if I wanted to double blur some elements I'd expect them to be double-blurred - as opposed to single-blurred ones).

Anyway, the overall effect you are trying to achieve can only be "tricked" by creating two parallel DOM structures: one that gets blurred and one that only displays the not-blurred element above the blurred "rest".

You're probably going to get the least expensive results using JavaScript and cloning, positioning and sizing the elements you want to see non-blurred inside a fixed positioned display wrapper, in `<body>`.
One thing is for sure: it's not a one-liner.

You're probably going to have a ***really hard time*** keeping the clone and the original in sync while scrolling and resizing page and, unless you come up with an attempt of your own, asking for it on SO is flat out *off-topic* for being *"too broad"* (too much to ask for in a single question).

Comment: Thanks for such a great explanation. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `body, not body#team.`

Untested but something like this should do it:

```
$('body').find('*').not('#team').css(/* whatever */)
```

Comment: Nope. it is still blurring the element I am hovering on. :(